# How to avoid my program stopping because of a invalid index number when calling a tuple

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a pokémon text based journey in python.
I listed the starter pokémon in a tuple to call the number that the user typed in the input to then store the chosen starter pokémon.

It all works but when the user would type a different integer then availabe in the tuple, for example: writing 5 while there are only 3 indexs in the tuple. The program just stops when this happens.

Is there a way for me to just tell the program to not go into debugging mode when this happens; and recalling the "ChoseStarter" function instead?

Here is the code:

```
if(ChosenPok == 1,ChosenPok == 2,ChosenPok == 3):

    ChosenPokInt = int(ChosenPok)
    StarterPok = Starter[ChosenPokInt-1] #Here is the problem

    Sure = f"You chose {StarterPok} are you sure? (y/n)"
    YORN = input(Sure)
    if(YORN == "Y" or YORN == "y"):
        Congrats = f"Congratulations!! You just got a {StarterPok}!!"
        WriteFast(Congrats)
        print(Starter[ChosenPokInt-1])
    else:
        WriteFast(ERROR)
        ChoseStarter()
```

Comment: Your first `if` clause does not make any sense. What are you trying to do?

Comment: It doesn't make any sense because the rest of my code isn't vissible, but for context I'm just trying to run the code when the player writes one of the 3 options (being 1 2 or 3) if he doesn't It'll ask again to pick an option.

Comment: That's not how you do it. Try `if 1 <= x <= 3`.

Comment: @TimoDino no, it doesn't make any sense because that's not how you check a variable against multiple values)

Comment: Oohh that's way better thank you so much!

Comment: what is the reason for: `ChosenPokInt = int(ChosenPok)`

Comment: ChosenPokInt is the variable where I store the converted string because when the input takes the input from the user it is a string and thuss cannot be changed with "-1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No idea what the question is about or what logic you want to implement. See if the below code helps though. Seems like the "if condition" is buggy in your case. The following code repeatedly asks for the correct input using a while loop. Replace the while loop with an if statement if you don't want that.

```py
starter = ["x", "y", "z"]
chosen_pok = int(input("Select a pok: "))

while not (1 < chosen_pok < 4):
  print("Invalid pok. try again...")
  chosen_pok = int(input("Select a pok: "))

starter_pok = starter[chosen_pok - 1]
yorn = input(f"You chose {starter_pok} are you sure? (y/n)")

if (yorn in ["Y", "y"]):
  print(starter[chosen_pok - 1])
else:
  print("Error")
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just check for the len and if ChosenPokInt is in it's boundaries:

```
pokemon_index = ChosenPokInt - 1
if 0 <= pokemon_index < len(Starter)-1:
    # everything is fine
else:
    # handle the problem case
```

Besides that I advice you to look into pep8 :). You can find an awesome guide here: https://pep8.org

Comment: Thank you so much that is so much better! I'm going to read the guide too much appriciated :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a while loop before the condition that checks first if the input is in the correct range:

```
ChosenPok = ChoseStarter()
pokRange = [1, 2, 3]
while not (ChosenPok in pokRange):
   print("Wrong input, try again")
   ChosenPok = ChoseStarter()
```